# `string.replace` weird behavior when using dollar sign ($) as replacement

Tags: javascript

I found a bug in my JavaScript code that I have isolated to a string replace that is acting in a way I didn't expect.  Here is an example of the code:

```
var text = "as";
text = text.replace(text,"$\'");
console.log(text);
```

This prints an empty string to the console.  I was expecting it to print $' to the console.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: More information can be found in the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.11. As Alex mentioned in his deleted answer, `$'` is a special character sequence which gets replaced by the string following the match. E.g. `"foobar".replace("foo", "$'")` becomes `barbar`.

Comment: See also [JavaScript replace() method dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38866071/1048572)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to use `$` in resulting string, use `$$` as `$` has special meaning in JavaScript Regular Expressions and String `replace` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: If I use $$, will other browsers understand that I want '$' rather than accepting it as a '$$' string literal? edit: It looks like this is standard JavaScript.  When I first asked the question about other browsers, it appeared to me that this was a quirk of Firefox.

Comment: this is standardized behavior and it works in IE too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/t0kbytzc(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I was unclear on whether this was standard JavaScript or a quirk of Firefox.

Comment: Fwiw: Painfully, odd numbered strings of `$` can have their replacement `$`s "round up", so to speak. So (using Chrome), `"1,2,3,4".replace(/,/g, "$$$")` gives `"1$$2$$3$$4"`. That is, here, **one escaped `$` plus one unescaped (ie, `$$$`) acts likes two escaped (`$$$$`)!** Makes the two-for-one escape pattern a little more difficult to sniff. ;^)

Answer (score 22):

If I don't know what is in my replacement string I use

```
replaceWith = "might have 2 $ signs $$ $$$ $$$$"
"a b c".replace("b", replaceWith) // unexpected result
"a b c".replace("b", function(){return replaceWith}) // no surprises
```

Comment: this is so simple and so useful! thanks, spared me some trouble, i was beginning to think about how to escape all `$` with `$`.. using regexes? obviously not a good idea!

Comment: This trick actually just saved my butt potentially everywhere in one of my projects due to templating within localizable strings used throughout. It was a little too much hassle to sort out what `$`s are meant to be escaped if any are given from user input or whatever. So much easier just to throw `() =>` before the string and be done with it.

Comment: Best reply, no need to mess around with escaping. The exact string you want to be inserted as the replacement is what it gets

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the most straight forward answer to this question is to use a function for the replacement string, because the w3c spec states that this result will not be affected by special characters.

```js
var str = "abc {def} ghi";

console.log(str.replace("{def}", function() {
  return "foo$'bar"; 
}));

// result is
// "abc foo$'bar ghi"
```

The MDN documentation for that is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace