# Literal dollar sign in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, asp.net, replace, expression

I am working with Canada (fr-CA) locale and trying to do following:

```
var str = "<dataset >{1}</dataset>";
var temp = "<set Cost x = '1,8M $' />";

str = str.replace(/\{1\}/g, temp);
```

OUTPUT:

```
"<dataset ><set Cost x = '1,8M  </dataset>" /></dataset>"
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
"<dataset ><set Cost x = '1,8M $'" /></dataset>"
```

replace function is misunderstanding `$`' from `'1,8M $'` as an expression and hence
repeating  in the output. Any ideas/workaround? Thank you for your time.

Comment: haven't see that one in a while, try "<set Cost x = '1,8M $$' />";

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423722/string-replace-weird-behavior-when-using-dollar-sign-as-replacement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$'` has a special meaning in the replacement string when using JS regular expressions: it inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring. To get a literal dollar sign in the replacement string, use `$$`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the ascii code for dollar sign? `&#36;`