# replacing a text with "$$$", gives truncated result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```
var text="$$$ $$ $"; 
var dummy="hello world"; 
dummy.replace("world", text);
```

expected output:

```
hello $$$ $$ $
```

actual output:

```
hello $$ $ $
```

i don't understand why this is happening. kindly help. it doesn't seem to happen with other symbols though.

thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions, which `replace` uses.

See this question for more details: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423722/string-replace-weird-behavior-when-using-dollar-sign-as-replacement)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "*because that's how String.replace works*".

The docs at Mozilla Development Network are helpful here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

The replacement string can include the following special replacement patterns:

- `$$`  Inserts a "$".
- `$&`  Inserts the matched substring.

And so forth.. (there's more replacement rules, but I'm not going to quote the whole MDN page)

So, if we change your sample to:

```
var text="$$ ($&) $"; 
var dummy="hello world"; 
dummy.replace("world", text);
```

We get as a result:

```
"hello $ (world) $"
```

In short `$&` (and other sequences like `$1` and `$'`), mean special things, and the way you escape a plain `$` is by preceding it with another `$`.