# Javascript Regex Function replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new in studying JavaScript. I have a String

```
var str2= "1 dollor plus 2 dollor equal 3 dollor";
```

and I want convert to

```
$1 plus $2 equal $3
```

So I using function Replace() Like this:

```
str2 = str2.replace(/(\d+)\s/g, '\$$&");
str2 = str2.replace(/dollor/g, '');
```

But I get this str:

```
$& plus $& equal $&
```

I change my code like this:

```
str2 = str2.replace(/(\d+)\s/g, '\$'+"$&");
```

It doesn't work.I know my question maybe stupid.But I really don't know why the "\" cant escape "$".
Forgive my poor English!

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`string.replace\` weird behavior when using dollar sign ($) as replacement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423722/string-replace-weird-behavior-when-using-dollar-sign-as-replacement)

Comment: I'm puzzled how you could have learned that `$&` in the replacement string refers to the match, but not that you need `$$` (not `\$`) to specify a literal dollar sign. The two sequences are almost certainly described together in virtually any tutorial on `replace` replacement strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.11) the replacement string for `$` is `$$`, not `\$`.  Given that, use this for your first replace line to produce the output you were looking for:

```
str2 = str2.replace(/(\d+)\s/g, '$$$&');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var str2= "1 dollor plus 2 dollor equal 3 dollor";

str2 = str2.replace(/(\d+)\s/g, function replaceWithReposition(x){return "$" + x});
```

I prepare a Fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/mez2yqb1/