# replace the string "Microsoft" with "W3Schools Test$'"

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to replace the string "Microsoft" with "W3Schools Test$".

Please note that there is single quotes after the dollar sign.

It is not working with my below code. You can see demo-one is working perfectly, but in case of demo-two its not working well.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str_one = document.getElementById("demo-one").innerHTML; 
    var res_one = str_one.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools Test$");
    document.getElementById("demo-one").innerHTML = res_one;
    
    var str_two = document.getElementById("demo-two").innerHTML; 
    var res_two = str_two.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools Test$'");
    document.getElementById("demo-two").innerHTML = res_two;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to replace "Microsoft" with "W3Schools" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo-one">Visit Microsoft!</p>
<p id="demo-two">Visit Microsoft!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Here is the output of the above code.

`Click the button to replace "Microsoft" with "W3Schools" in the paragraph below:
Visit W3Schools Test$!
Visit W3Schools Test!!`

Third line should show as `Visit W3Schools Test$'` but it showing as `Visit W3Schools Test!!`

Please help me to get out from this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I would like to replace the string "Microsoft" with "W3Schools Test$'"` out of the frying pan, into the fire

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript replace() method dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866071/javascript-replace-method-dollar-signs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) , `$'` is use to inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.

To insert `$` using the `string#replace`, use `$$`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str_one = document.getElementById("demo-one").innerHTML; 
    var res_one = str_one.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools Test$");
    document.getElementById("demo-one").innerHTML = res_one;
    
    var str_two = document.getElementById("demo-two").innerHTML; 
    var res_two = str_two.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools Test$$'");
    console.log(res_two);
    document.getElementById("demo-two").innerHTML = res_two;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to replace "Microsoft" with "W3Schools" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo-one">Visit Microsoft!</p>
<p id="demo-two">Visit Microsoft!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
        var str_one = document.getElementById("demo-one").innerHTML; 
        var res_one = str_one.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools Test$$'");
        document.getElementById("demo-one").innerHTML = res_one;
        
        var str_two = document.getElementById("demo-two").innerHTML; 
        var res_two = str_two.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools Test$$'");
        document.getElementById("demo-two").innerHTML = res_two;
    }
```

```html
<p>Click the button to replace "Microsoft" with "W3Schools" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo-one">Visit Microsoft!</p>
<p id="demo-two">Visit Microsoft!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```