# Problems with Dollar Sign in Replace method

Tags: node.js

In my code I read a variable from JSON file. The Variable is a $ sign.

It looks like:

```
  "jsonTest":{
    "doJson":"true",
    "steps":[
      {
        "path": "$",
        "compare": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
```

No I read this variable with JSON Path and do an console.log

```
console.log(entry.path);
```

Result is the Expected $

Now I added this to a string:

```
addJsonTests += '   .expect(await getJSONInfo(\''+ entry.path +'\')).eql(\''+ entry.compare +'\',\'JSON Wertvergleich fehlgeschlagen\', {timeout: 40000}) \n';
```

Text I got back in console.log is:

.expect(await getJSONInfo('$')).eql('test','JSON Wertvergleich fehlgeschlagen', {timeout: 40000})

So here the $ is still existing. 
Now I replace this text with a placeholder and write it back to a physical file. Now the physical file looks like:

```
        await t 
   .expect(await getJSONInfo('

    });)).eql('test','JSON Wertvergleich fehlgeschlagen', {timeout: 40000})
```

The $ sign is gone. I think it will be lost in replace function. This looks like:

```
tempData = tempData.replace('%%JSONTest%%',addJsonTests);
```

After this line the string is damaged. Any idea why this happen with $ sign?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it is the special pattern issue. To get a $ in the replace method it need to get a $$ in the input string.

Seen on:
[JavaScript replace() method dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866071/javascript-replace-method-dollar-signs)