# JavaScript $ sign unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
S = "$answer"
S = S.replace('$answer', "'test$'")
console.log(S)
```

The code above outputs `'test` instead of `'test$'` as I would expect it to.
What's going on here?

Comment: My workaround is to reverse the quotes as such: `S.replace('$answer', '"test$"')` , yet I don't understand why `$'` behaves that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript replace() method dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866071/javascript-replace-method-dollar-signs)

Comment: There's an explanation on `MDN` under `Description` why this is happening - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace - `$'` is considered a special replacement pattern

Comment: thanks @goto1 ! I must've overlooked it.